# Resize of table-cell to zero

Tags: html, css

Can you please help with this. There's probably some solution for this without javascript and @media.

[Image for better understanding my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufl4R.png)

All the details are in it, but there's no much of it. The main problem is to get the right and left columns resize to zero with the window/resolution changes, but i'm getting a hard time with it

```
.table {
    min-width: 399px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.table-cell-left {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 9999px;
    width: 49%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#933333;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.table-cell-right {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 9999px;
    width: 49%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#339933;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-cell-middle {
    min-width: 399px;
    max-width: 999px;
    width: 2%;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#333393;
    color: #ffffff;
}

<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell-left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell-middle">
        Middle
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell-right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/densssky/2etbx07g/)
Thanks!

Comment: If the cells are empty (no text) then they'll resize down to zero width. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But with content inside. Also, there's a problem with middle section... it's stretching more than 999px and i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
.table {
    min-width: 399px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.table-cell-left {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 9999px;
    width: 49%;        //remove this
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#933333;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.table-cell-right {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 9999px;
    width: 49%;         // remove this
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#339933;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-cell-middle {
    min-width: 399px;
    max-width: 999px;
    width: 2%;         // remove this
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#333393;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work... the middle section is stretching more than 999px. And as the result, the left and right columns fit only the width of the content... but i want it stretch for maximum

Comment: Then just remove width : 2%,no need to set it to 100%

Comment: That's not working... the middle will and it is stretching for 100% because of the .table class, and the desirable effect would be gone, because i want sides to fit the maximum size

Comment: I guess I am not getting what are you trying to do.